# Can we use a sort of "meta-induction" when proving facts about ZFC?

Tags: logic, set-theory

In this [mathoverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32538/finite-axiom-of-choice-how-do-you-prove-it-from-just-zf), (almost) all answers mention that ZF proves a finite version of AoC because we can perform a sort of induction to construct the choice function. It seems to me that this "induction" is something that we perform in the metatheory that we're using to analyze ZF, since ZF by itself doesn't have any sort of induction axiom. Is this correct?

If so, is it the case that we can only really do finite induction in this way? I think this might be the case; what we're arguing is this: we show $\textrm{ZF} \vdash P_0$ and that $\textrm{ZF}, P_n \vdash P_{n + 1}$ for some sequence of sentences $P_0, P_1, P_2, \dots$. The finite induction then basically says that $ZF \vdash ZF, P_0 \vdash ZF, P_1 \vdash \cdots \vdash ZF, P_n$ for some $n$. This, I think, is fine, as it is a finite "stacking" of $\vdash$-s, the transitivity of which is a logical property. But, as far as I'm aware, there's no logical property which allows for stacking of countably (infinitely) many $\vdash$-s, so a full induction can not be done like this. That's why I would conclude, for example, that ZF doesn't prove the countable AoC, but I'm not sure of this. Is this correct?

Can someone formulate what I said above a little more formally (if it's correct)? I've confused myself here a bit.

Comment: "It seems to me that this "induction" is something that we perform in the metatheory that we're using to analyze ZF, since ZF by itself doesn't have any sort of induction axiom. Is this correct?" No, this is not correct: it's a completely valid ZF proof. ZF doesn't have an induction axiom explicitly but it does **prove** an appropriate induction scheme (namely, that $\omega$ is well-ordered).

Comment: Does that mean that ZF proves countable AoC, too? Also, if I'm understanding correctly, we're then using ZF(C) as a metatheory to analyze ZF(C), so ZFC proves that ZF proves finite AoC. Right?

Comment: @zaq To your first question: no, the argument breaks down at limit steps. To the second question: we can use a *much weaker* metatheory, e.g. PA proves that ZF proves finite AoC. Indeed *any theory capable of doing basic arithmetic* can verify that ZF proves finite AoC; there's no interesting meta-theoretic question to ask there.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the argument breaks down for the countable case? This seems odd to me, as I'm used to seeing functions constructed on e.g. $\mathbb{N}$ by induction (and these constructions aren't wrong, no?).

Comment: @zaq Induction on $\mathbb N$ proves something is true for all $n\in \mathbb N,$ not that it is true for $\omega.$ There's no way to get a choice function on a countable set from the mere fact that you can get a choice function on any finite subset. Note that any strategy you might try to construct it from an infinite number of finite choice functions is doomed since you would need AC to choose the choice functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use this principle of induction which can be proved within ZFC to prove a finite version of the AC:

*if $φ(n)$ is a formula from first order logic with $n$ a free variable,  $ω$ is the set of all natural numbers and $B=\{n|n∈ω∧ φ(n)\}$ is an inductive set then $φ(n)$ is true for all $n∈ω$.*

A natural number is defined as a set that belongs to every inductive set and it is easy to show, using the infinity axiom, that there is a set of natural numbers. And we can show that the set of natural numbers is inductive and a subset of every inductive set. Hence $ω⊆B$ and so as it's clear from the definition that $B⊆ω$,  $B=ω$ and $φ(n)$ is true for all $n∈ω$.

Comment: Thank you. How come we can't construct a choice function for a countable set using this principle?

Comment: In our proof of finite AC the induction hypothesis is that every finite collection of non-empty sets has a choice function. We use the principle of induction to show that this is true for all finite sets. The proof can't be generalized to allow us to show it is true for countable sets.